# "None" appears before matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I wrote a program that generates matrix 7x7 and then rotates it and transposing it. In output i see this "None"

```
import time
import numpy as np
matsize = np.array([7,7])
matrix = np.random.randint(1000,size=(matsize))
print('\nSwource matrix:\n', matrix, '\n')

rotmatr = np.rot90(matrix, k=-1)
print('Rotation to 90 degrees...\n')
print(time.sleep(2), rotmatr, '\n')

transpos = np.transpose(rotmatr)
print('Transposing...\n')
print(time.sleep(2), transpos)
```

example of how the code works

```
Swource matrix:
 [[909 859 984 490 773 696 576]
 [780 645 632 233 109 181  18]
 [ 81 890 328 746 930  45 999]
 [944 992 556 436 545 210 814]
 [192 827 820 321  45 959 940]
 [921 529 276 996 141 132 183]
 [235 842 287 169  71 857  70]] 

Rotation to 90 degrees...

None [[235 921 192 944  81 780 909]
 [842 529 827 992 890 645 859]
 [287 276 820 556 328 632 984]
 [169 996 321 436 746 233 490]
 [ 71 141  45 545 930 109 773]
 [857 132 959 210  45 181 696]
 [ 70 183 940 814 999  18 576]] 

Transposing...

None [[235 842 287 169  71 857  70]
 [921 529 276 996 141 132 183]
 [192 827 820 321  45 959 940]
 [944 992 556 436 545 210 814]
 [ 81 890 328 746 930  45 999]
 [780 645 632 233 109 181  18]
 [909 859 984 490 773 696 576]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What this NONE is and how to delete it???

Answer (score 1):

if you remove the `time.sleep(2)` from your `print` statements, that will remove the `None`

Answer (score 1):

```
print(time.sleep(2), transpos)
```

Prints two items:

- the return value of `time.sleep(2)` which is None
- the matrix in `transpos`

To remove None, move the sleep to its own line:

```
time.sleep(2)
print(transpos)
```

Comment: yeah, did that thing. thanks for the explanation :)

i am a novice here and i already love the stackoverflow, got the answer in only 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the `time.sleep(2)` just remove it and put it above the `print`